# Create Two Dataframes From One By Adding Distinct Data in One Column

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, iteration

I am new to python and struggling with a pretty basic concept, so bear with me. Please accept my apologies.

Objetive:
I have an existing dataframe
I want to take the existing dataframe and create two separate versions (variables "df_1" and "df_2") based on it. They will be the same except they will have different country_ids.

See Desired Output for dataframe 1 ("df_1")

```
     name   occupation  country_id
     mike   plumber     123
     mary   plumber     123
     joe    plumber     123
```

See Desired Output for dataframe 2 ("df_2")

```
     name   occupation  country_id
     mike   plumber     456
     mary   plumber     456
     joe    plumber     456
```

My Code

```
    country_id_1 = 123
    country_id_2 = 456

    df_0 = 
    name    occupation
    mike    plumber
    mary    plumber
    joe     plumber

    df_1 = df_0
    df_2 = df_0

    df_1['country_id'] = df_1.shape[0]*[country_id_1]
    df_2['country_id'] = df_2.shape[0]*[country_id_2]
```

When I Print I Get This Result

```
   print(df_1['country_id'] = df_1.shape[0]*[country_id_1])
   print(df_2['country_id'] = df_2.shape[0]*[country_id_2])


   name occupation  country_id
   mike plumber 456
   mary plumber 456
   joe  plumber 456

   name occupation  country_id
   mike plumber 456
   mary plumber 456
   joe  plumber 456
```

It's obviously referring to the last variable I used (country_Id_2). I'm sure a loop/iteration would solve this but I do need two variables at the end of the day. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The error is that `df_0`, `df_1` and `df_2` are the same dataframe because you do `df_1 = df_0` and `df_2 = df_0`. Just add `copy()` such as `df_1 = df_0.copy()` and same for `df_2 = df_0.copy()` and it should solve the problem you have

Answer (score 0):

Use [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) to create a new column, and it will create appropriate copies for you:

```
country_id_1 = 123
country_id_2 = 456

df_1 = df_0.assign(country_id=country_id_1)

df_2 = df_0.assign(country_id=country_id_2)

>>> df_1
   name occupation  country_id
0  mike    plumber         123
1  mary    plumber         123
2   joe    plumber         123
>>> df_2
   name occupation  country_id
0  mike    plumber         456
1  mary    plumber         456
2   joe    plumber         456
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.copy()` with broadcasting, with `df` being your existing dataframe:

```
df1 = df.copy()
df1['country_id'] = 123
df2 = df.copy()
df2['country_id'] = 456
```